# MOSS 2007 announcements webpart not showing complete data

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have created an Anouncement list in MOSS 2007 and I am showing the Announcements webpart on the home page. But the webpart is not displaying complete data. Is there anyway i can increase the length of the data shown. Please advise. My client wants to see the complete information and I donot know how to do it.

```
**for exapmple** 
**Complete text:**

Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata TestdataTestdataTestdataTestdata datavvTestdataTestdataTestdatavvvvvcontiune to If you need to call emergencey after hours service their number is 00000000000.  Please contact if you have any questions.

**Output:**

Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata Testdata TestdataTestdataTestdataTestdata datavvTestdataTestdataTestdatavvvvvcontiune to If you need to call emergencey...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is possible [using SharePoint Designer](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2009/02/expanding-size-of-announcements-web.html).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Response. I tried doing it in the similar way, but the look and feel of the announcements webpart is changing. The webpart looking something similar to a list webpart. How can i retain the similar look and feel of Announcements webpart?